# Remove min height from iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, height, min

I have tried to remove the min-height several ways from this `iFrame`. But none of them work. I can't find my answer online so I have resulted to asking the question myself.

The `iFrame` I'm having trouble with is on this webpage:
https://www.prolifedistribution.co.uk/procast-i103

The `iFrame` is the anchor embed. As you can see, you can scroll on the iframe as it has a unwanted space at the bottom. I can't leave it there and revert back to showing it, as it's just too big and I need to add other anchor iFrames underneath.

Let me know what I should try and I will see if it works.

Comment: Please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the content inside the iframe has a min-height value set to 300px, so thats why the scrollbar appears. Since you don't have access to Anchor's code, the only way to fix this is to disable scrolling on the iframe. One way to do this is to add the `scrolling="no"` attribute to the iframe. This is not valid in HTML5 though, but browsers still support it.

Comment: I tried adding scrolling="no"... it didnt seem to work, tried adding it in html and css, neither worked, anything else I could try?